# JWS launch: "To restart Deployment Toolkit, please refresh the web page"

Tags: javascript, jnlp, java-web-start, deployjava, java-deployment-toolkit

I'm using the deployJava.js together with a primefaces commandbutton to launch a java web start app. Now this works perfectly on my own computers and browsers, but some users get the following popup

"To restart Deployment Toolkit, please refresh the web page".

Refreshing and then click button again just renders the same result.

[image]

The relevant code in play:

```
<h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Launch" onclick="javascript:
            if (!deployJava.isWebStartInstalled(&quot;1.7.0&quot;)) {
            if (deployJava.installLatestJRE()) {
            if (deployJava.launch(&quot;myjnlp.jnlp&quot;)) {}}} else {
            if (deployJava.launch(&quot;myjnlp.jnlp&quot;)) {}}" 
        />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

I realise one solution to this problem likely is to do some setting on the client browser/system and if you know which one an answer is welcome.

But ideally I would want to change the code to also cover this use case without client-side workarounds.

Comment: Does it work for all browsers using the standard 'write applet element on load' function?